# Cannot hibernate on Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, hibernate

I get this error - slightly different to all the others I've seen as it says "supported" at the end:

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.failed:Operation not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have you set up your home folder to be encrypted at the installation of ubuntu, I will suggest you to have a look at the following website for explanations about how to set up a password instead of a random key for swap encryption:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnableHibernateWithEncryptedSwap#Explanation

But before following the explanations from there, I would suggest you to check up if your swap is encrypted, you can do that by typing the following in the terminal:

$    swapon --summary

You should see output similar to:

```
You should see output similar to:

         Filename                 Type         Size    Used    Priority

/dev/mapper/cryptswap1          partition    1998844    0       -1
```

If you do not see cryptswap1, the partition is either unencrypted or is not encrypted to Ubuntu's standard.